# How to set output of FFmpeg to output of a video card instead of a file? Is this possible?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, c#

I have an UltraStudio-SDI video card and I can capture with this command:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -video_size 720x576 -framerate 60 -i video="Decklink Video Capture":audio="Decklink Audio Capture" -r 30 -threads 2 -vcodec libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

How can I get a video signal from the output of the video card instead of from the output.mp4 file?

Is this possible in FFmpeg or in other tools or other libraries for use in C# code? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

FFplay syntax would be:

```
ffplay -f dshow -video_size 720x576 -framerate 60 -i video="Decklink Video Capture":audio="Decklink Audio Capture"
```

Answer (score -1):

FFmpeg comes with a utility called FFplay that should do what you’re looking for.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include exactly how to use `ffplay` to achieve what is being asked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide at least a link, as well some additional information about the software itself, for example how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.